# Transact SQL : Only most recent changes if 2 columns value are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to write a SQL request that'll fetch the user in my database, but here's the trick, if there's the same email twice, i only want to fetch the most recent one ( i have a time stamp in my db )

Here's the SQL CODE

```
 SELECT cs_login, cs_email_opt_out_did 
 FROM dbo.individual 
 WHERE insert_date >= '2016-12-05 00:00:00' and insert_date < dateadd(day,1,'2016-12-05 23:59:59')
```

`cs_login` is the email adress i want to check for duplicate 
`cs_email_opt_oud_did` is a boolean which values doesn't matter
`insert_date` is the timestamp on which i want to check the latest date

My problem is i have 2 email address `user@test.com` with a different `cs_email_opt_out_did` value. I don't how to could i select the one with the most recent date value from the `insert_date` colums

Comment: Transact-SQL is not used in mysql!! why adding it's tag

Comment: If you supply some sample data, and expected output, you are more likely to get a working answer.  See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056) for some great tips.  You can use a [windowed function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use **Ranking windows function** like [DENSE_RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

```
 SELECT cs_login, cs_email_opt_out_did  FROM (
 SELECT cs_login,cs_email_opt_out_did,insert_date, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cs_login ORDER BY insert_date Desc) as [Rank]
 FROM dbo.individual 
 WHERE insert_date >= '2016-12-05 00:00:00' and insert_date < dateadd(day,1,'2016-12-05 23:59:59')) AS T1
 WHERE T1.[Rank] = 1
```

you can also use other functions like [RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) AND [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: I wouldn't say you HAVE to... it's just ONE way and you for got to order your insert_date DESC. Since ASC is the default, this will returned the FIRST not the LAST (most recent) record.

Comment: @scsimon i replaced it.

Comment: @Hadi wouldn't you want to `order by insert_date descending`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function inside a cte like this:

```
with cte as (
  select 
      cs_login
    , cs_email_opt_out_did 
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by cs_login order by insert_date desc)
  from dbo.individual
  where insert_date >= '2016-12-05 00:00:00' 
    and insert_date < dateadd(day,1,'2016-12-05 23:59:59')
      )
select 
    cs_login
  , cs_email_opt_out_did
  from cte
  where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the record with the `MAX(insert_date)`

```
SELECT i.cs_login, i.cs_email_opt_out_did 
FROM dbo.individual i
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT cs_login, MAX(insert_date) dt FROM dbo.individual GROUP BY cs_login) as  i2
    ON i2.dt = i.insert_date and i2.cs_login = i.cs_login
WHERE i.insert_date >= '2016-12-05 00:00:00' and i.insert_date < dateadd(day,1,'2016-12-05 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the the With Ties clause.  No need for a sub-query or cte

```
 Select Top 1 With Ties 
        cs_login
      , cs_email_opt_out_did 
  From dbo.individual
  Where insert_date >= '2016-12-05 00:00:00' and insert_date < dateadd(day,1,'2016-12-05 23:59:59')
  Order By Row_Number() over(Partition By cs_login Order By insert_date desc)
```